# SQLite command construct WHERE clause

Tags: c#, sqlite, t-sql

How to use `Combobox.SelectedValue` to construct WHERE clause?

```
conL.Open();
cmdL.Connection = conL;
cmdL.CommandText ="SELECT Id FROM dbAllServers WHERE Server_Names='" + cmb_SQLNames.SelectedValue +"'";
SQLiteDataReader r = cmdL.ExecuteReader();
while(r.Read())
{
    serID = int.Parse(r[0].ToString());
    MessageBox.Show("Current Selected Server ID is:..." + serID.ToString());
}
conL.Close();
```

Comment: A part from the dangerous string concatenation, what is the problem with this code?

Comment: if you print 'cmb_SQLNames.SelectedValue' do you get your expected filter value?

Comment: Use parameterized query instead of concatenating combobox value in query string. What problem you have with the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example of parameterized query, might be helpful:

```
string query = "SELECT Id FROM dbAllServers WHERE Server_Names=@server_name";

string serverName = cmb_SQLNames.SelectedValue;

using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(GetConnectionString()))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, connection))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@server_name", serverName));
        using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                // do your job  here
            }
        }
    }
}
```